# How can I add pop up box into elevation event calendar plugin in rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to add a pop up box into event calendar plugin to show event's details when we click on the event. According to the mouse event it should pop up a box rather than redirecting to the new page. And also in that pop up box i want to give edit and delete functions to the user. I am using rails 2.3. Can anybody help me to add this functionality? I used [event_calendar](https://github.com/elevation/event_calendar) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The pop up is part of JavaScript. Have you included the following in you application layout file?

```
public/stylesheets/event_calendar.css
public/javascripts/event_calendar.js
```

Comment: To Simpleton: Hv u ever work with event calendar on Jquery Model dialog box ?